# Ubuntu is not installing on Virtual box with error of not enough space while I do have the space

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I have followed all the steps to install Ubuntu on the VirtualBox but the installer puts a cross in front of the requirement "free space of more than 6.6GB" while I have around 7.5 Gb free space on my C drive. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a virtual drive that is less than 6.6GB.

It does not matter how much space you have "on your C drive", because the virtual machine sees only the virtual drive.

When you create a virtual machine you are asked to specify the amount of space you assign to the virtual disk. But in your case you may run out of disk space.

Comment: @SiddhantJain please accept this answer by clicking the checkmark bellow the arrows to make it green. This will help other users in future to find information more easily

Comment: @Pilot6 I suggest you edit the answer to include info on how to resize the virtual disk. At least a link will suffice. Upgoated

Comment: I am afraid that if there is only 7.5 GB on disk, it will be not possible. But I will add some information.

Comment: I cleared more space on my C drive to make free space more than 8GB

Answer (score 0):

Even on limited or in your case very limited hard drive space VirtualBox allows creating virtual drives of up to 2 TB **virtual** size. This does not depend on the physical space we have as long as it is a **dynamically allocated file**.

By this we can create a virtual drive much bigger than physical space available. This has the advantage to later move this drive to another location where we may have fewer hardware limits. But we will get an error with possible data loss as soon as we try to grow this disk to more than physically possible.

To further save hard drive space consider installing Ubuntu without a swap.